# Java- How to use the library jlayer to play audio?

Tags: java, eclipse, api, audio, jlayer

I am trying to use an API by JZoom called JLayer which allows one to play audio files among other things. I downloaded the JLayer 1.0.1 version. Here is the link to their website: [http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/sources.html](http://website).I have found this code which attempts to play an audio file called `audio.mp3`:

```
import javazoom.jl.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Sound {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Sam\\Desktop\\dreamBeatsWorkspace\\dreamBeats\\audio.mp3");
            Player playMP3 = new Player(file);
            playMP3.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

When I write this in Eclipse it underlines the `Player` part of `Player playMP3 = new Player(file);` and asks for a Player class. I assume this means that the Player class is not defined. On the other hand I have tried to download and implement the JLayer library by going to `Window->Preferences->Java->Build Path->User Libraries`. Then I created a new folder called `audio lib` and went to `Add External JARS...` from their I chose the files `jl1.0.1` in `C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\jlayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1`, `Player.class` in `C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\jlayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1\classes\javazoom\jl\player` and `Player.java` in `C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\jlayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1\src\javazoom\jl\player` then hit open for all of them and finally I hit OK. I proceed to write my code in a new class I created called Sound. Finally when I ran this code this error message popped up in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Player cannot be resolved to a type
    Player cannot be resolved to a type

    at Sound.main(Sound.java:9)
```

I am assuming I need to find a way to make a class path to where the Player class is defined. I don't know how to do this and Ideas on **how to build a class path to the location of the Player class in the Eclipse software** would be very helpful. All ideas on **what went wrong** and **how one can play an audio file with the JLayer library** would be much appreciated. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try to introduce the library (jl1.0.1.jar) straight in your project ,
right click on your project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jar then Ok , Clean project and run again

Answer (score 0):

Re write the first line of your code from -

```
import javazoom.jl.*; 

TO 

import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
```

This should solve the compilation problem

Comment: the website now is dissapeared ...

Answer (score 0):

Your project should be a Maven project.

1, download this jar file from here https://jar-download.com/artifacts/javazoom/jlayer/1.0.1/source-code

2,click your project title, -> new -> directory -> create a folder called lib -> move the jar file you download to lib folder

3, need to configure it as a dependency: click the jar file -> new-> add as a library, then it becomes your part of your project.